# Mask the Loss function for segmantic segmentation in tf keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have images of the size `(256,256)` that are segmented into 10 classes (`0` to `9`).
I want to train a semantic segmentation network on this data set but only want to treat it as a 9 class problem (i.e. ignore class `2`).

My question is if there is something like a mask I can parse where the loss is not evaluated.

My current approach is: 
I am modifying the corresponding area of the picture before the one hot encoding, i.e.:

```py
# change any pixel with value 2 to 255
target = tf.where(target==2,tf.constant(255,shape=(256, 256), dtype=tf.uint8),target) 

# change 3 -> 2, 4 -> 3, ..., 9 -> 8    
for i in range(3,10):
    target = tf.where(target==i,tf.constant(i-1,shape=(256, 256), dtype=tf.uint8),target)

# do one hot
out = tf.one_hot(target,9)
```

and train a network with a 9 class output. All the pixels that used to be with the value `2`
are one-hot encoded to `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]` and should not count to the loss function (categorical_crossentropy). Anyway I am not sure If that produces problems as we divide by the number of pixels (constant 256^2) and that would reduce the influence of the other labels if a large part of the image is labeled by an zero vector.

I am using `tf.keras` with `Tensorflow 2.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a weight vector to achieve what you need here.

```
# Creating a random vector of targets of size (128)
target = tf.constant(np.random.randint(0,10, size=128).astype(np.int32))
# Create weights of size (128) and reshape to (128,1)
weights = tf.cast(tf.not_equal(target, 2), tf.float32)[:,tf.newaxis]

# do one hot and multiply by weights
out = tf.one_hot(target,9) * weights
```

Having said that, this is to get a vector of zeros. But the standard way to ignore those pixels would be to multiply the actual crossentropy loss by the weight instead of the onehot vectors.

```
out = tf.one_hot(target,9)
# pred is the predictions made
loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()(out, pred) * weights
```

This will make the loss ignore the pixels with value 2.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Isn't multiplying the loss by the weight vector still reducing the influence of the non two pixels? Because at the end we would still divide by the total number of pixels and if  lets say the weight vector consists of 90% zeros we would sum up 12 numbers but still divide by 128.

Comment: For that divide by `tf.sum(weights)` instead of batch size. Then you're essentially taking that effect off